# lfortran in a jupyter notebook kills kernel

Tags: jupyter-notebook, fortran, jupyter-kernel

I can't seem to get output from the [lfortran jupyter kernel](https://lfortran.org/).

I installed via conda install for:

```
  - lfortran
  - jupyter
```

I can run `jupyter` and select the lfortran kernel.  However:

[image: Hello World does nothing]

I see no hello world and also no error.

If in a second cell I call `new` it crashes the kernel.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The global scope in LFortran is special to enable interactivity and usage in a notebook and defines a set of additional rules. You actually don't need a `program` body to run any Fortran code there, just using the print statement directly will work:

```
print *, "Hello world!"
```

The extensions to Fortran available are described [here](https://docs.lfortran.org/design/#lfortran-extension).

Further, a `program` itself is not supposed to be callable, rather it should execute directly after being declared (this might be a bug in LFortran, reported it in [lfortran#648](https://gitlab.com/lfortran/lfortran/-/issues/648)). Instead you might want to declare a `subroutine`:

```
subroutine new
  print *, "Hello world!"
end subroutine new
```

And than run it with

```
call new
```